# ArcMap ModelBuilder: Select Annotation from iteration of CAD (.dxf) files and then import them into a geodatabase

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, dxf, annotation, error-000622

I'm trying to build a model which exports the "Annotations" and the "Area", "Line", "CadDoc" (after running the Import from CAD tool) of several DXF files and then append them to an already existing geodatabase. Except for the Annotations the model seems to work.

[image: Model]

But I can't seem to select/access the Annotation feature from the CAD file which is the output of the "iterate datasets", with the model tool "select data". I've tried to put "Annotation" into percent signs for the "Child Data Element", but it only produces an Error when I try to run the model.

[image: Select Annotations from CAD file]

[image: Error for the Annotation]

Error:

> ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (ImportCADAnnotation). Parameters are not valid.
> ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Layer.
> Failed to execute (Import CAD Annotation).

When I put in the .dxf file directly into the model and modify the tools to that it works and I can select the Annotation from the file. The problem definetely seems to be the iteration. Is there a way to access the annotation from the iterated CAD file so I can run the "Import CAD Annotation" tool?